# Limit of a sequence, possibly requires epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
>     and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are sequences for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n=0.$

This is what I have so far

Becuase $b_n$ is bounded, this means it has to be convergent and thus it has a limit, call this $q$.

By the algebra of limits,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot b_n = (\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)(\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n)
= 0*q =0 \ .
$$
How could I do this using an epsilon delta proof, or is this not necessary for this question?

Comment: A bounded sequence need not have a limit.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B$ be a bound for $(b_n)$, that is, $|b_n|\le B$ for all $n$.

Then,
$
|a_n b_n| \le |a_n| B \to 0
$.

Comment: There's an implicit appeal to the Squeeze Thm here.

Comment: @Vim, not really: 
$
|a_n b_n-0| \le |a_n-0| B < \varepsilon B
$.

Comment: @Vim: Yes, if one wants to avoid the $\epsilon, \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the upper bound of $\{b_n\}$ by $B^*$ and the lower bound by $B_*$.

Then we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$B_*|a_n| \le b_n |a_n| \le B^*|a_n|$$

Now clearly we have:

$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} B_* a_n = B_* \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} a_n =0$$

and

$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} B^* a_n = B^* \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} a_n =0$$

hence by the sandwich theorem it follows immediately that:

$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} b_n |a_n| = 0.$$

I imagine you can take it from here; the rest is just tedious accounting for all of the possible combinations of signs.